# Is there an imperative command to create daemonsets in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

I was wondering if there is an easier way to create daemonsets in k8s other than yaml files.
For eg, for pods we have `kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1` command. I was wondering if there is something similar for DS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such quick `kubectl create` type command for creating `daemonsets`. But you can do it in some other way.

- One way to do this is:

  ```bash
  $ kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx --dry-run=client -o yaml | \
      sed '/null\|{}\|replicas/d;/status/,$d;s/Deployment/DaemonSet/g' > nginx-ds.yaml
  $ kubectl apply -f nginx-ds.yaml
  ```
- If you don't want to save the `yaml` data to any file, here's how you can do this:

  ```bash
  $ kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx --dry-run=client -o yaml | \
      sed '/null\|{}\|replicas/d;/status/,$d;s/Deployment/DaemonSet/g' | \
      kubectl apply -f -
  ```

You have your daemonset now.

What we are doing here is: at first we're creating a deployment `yaml` and then replacing `kind: Deployment` with `kind: DaemonSet` and remove `replicas: 1` from the deployment `yaml`.

Thats's how we get `yaml` for `daemonset`.

Comment: We also have to remove `status` and `strategy`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can access [Kubernetes Documentation for DaemonSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/). You could use the link and get examples of DaemonSet yaml files. However there is no way you could create a Daemonset by imperative way. You could create a deployment specification and  change the deployment specification to DaemonSet specification. You need to change the **kind** to **Daemonset**, remove *strategy, replicas and status* fields. That would do.